# Get schema of proc's select output

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I'd like to put the results of a stored proc into a temp table.  It seems that the temp table must be defined beforehand and an INSERT INTO will not work.

Anyone know how to get the schema of the recordset being returned from a select statement?

sp_help only gets info on parameters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to insert into a temp table without defining the schema using OPENQUERY:

```
SELECT * INTO #TempTable
FROM OPENQUERY(ServerName, ‘EXEC DataBaseName.dbo.StoredProcedureName paramvalues1, paramvalues1′)
```

Where ServerName is the name of your Sql Server instance.  See [this article](http://munishbansal.wordpress.com/2008/04/29/inserting-results-of-a-stored-procedurefunction-into-a-temp-table/) for more info

Comment: do it support any other database then master as it work in master table only

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes you just need to know the schema without creating a table. This command outputs the structure of the resultset without actually executing the stored procedure.

From [rachmann](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/profile/rachmann/?ws=usercard-mini) on 16 April, 2015 from the Microsoft SQL Server forum article [How to get schema of resultset returned by a stored procedure without using OPENQUERY?](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/5add6875-4e27-499a-8388-1062da8ea21d/how-to-get-schema-of-resultset-returned-by-a-stored-procedure-without-using-openquery?forum=transactsql):

```
SELECT * FROM sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set ('owner.sprocName', NULL, 0) ;
```

Comment: should be the selected answer

Answer (score 0):

Can you execute the logical content including INSERT INTO in a query window? That should generate a temp table that you can use as a model.

Worst case you build the schema by hand, once, which shouldn't be onerous if you are the one writing the SP.

For the benefit of future documentation, I like to hand-craft DDL in SPs anyway. It helps when debugging to have the schema explicitly at hand.

Comment: like I said, insert into doesn't seem to work.  Maybe I'm doing something wrong, but I doubt it.  

>>Worst case you build the schema by hand, once, which shouldn't be onerous if you are the one writing the SP.
I don't write them and am looking for an easy way.

Comment: Explain what you mean "doesn't seem to work". You can't get access? Doesn't ever work for any query? Are you able to try? What error is returned? What does your query look like?

Comment: Do you think this should work? SELECT * INTO sp_who FROM EXEC sp_who

Answer (score 0):

If you are able, change the stored procedure into a user-defined function.

http://www.scottstonehouse.ca/blog/2007/03/stored-procedures-are-not-parameterized.html